# nix: override doCheck in pybind11

Tags: nix

Looking at: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/libraries/pybind11/default.nix, it seemed to me that I should be able to avoid running tests (i.e., set `-DPYBIND11_TEST=OFF`) with something like the following:

```
pybind11 = pkgs.pybind11.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
   doCheck = false;
});
```

This, however, does not work.

I solved my problem by modifying cmakeFlags directly:

```
  pybind11 = pkgs.pybind11.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
      cmakeFlags = [
        "-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=${pkgs.python.interpreter}"
        "-DPYBIND11_TEST=OFF"
      ];
  });
```

But I was wondering why the former approach does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the derivation is using the `rec` keyword, which doesn't have a concept of overriding. An extract:

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, fetchFromGitHub, cmake, catch, python, eigen }:

stdenv.mkDerivation rec { #0
  name = "pybind-${version}";
  version = "2.2.4";

  doCheck = true; #1

  cmakeFlags = [ 
    "-DPYBIND11_TEST=${if doCheck then "ON" else "OFF"}"
  ];
}
```

With `.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: { doCheck = false; })` you only override the `doCheck` attribute, but not the `cmakeFlags`, which still references the `doCheck` (`#1`) from the lexical scope introduced by the `rec {}` (`#0`)

So the following is equivalent to the snippet above:

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, fetchFromGitHub, cmake, catch, python, eigen }:

stdenv.mkDerivation (let #0
  name = "pybind-${version}";
  version = "2.2.4";

  doCheck = true; #1

  cmakeFlags = [ 
    "-DPYBIND11_TEST=${if doCheck then "ON" else "OFF"}"
  ];
in { #0
  name = name;
  version = version;
  doCheck = doCheck; #1
  cmakeFlags = cmakeFlags;
}
```

`mkDerivation` can only see the attrset it gets, but can not introspect and modify the expression that builds that attrset. This a necessary Nix language design principle because it lets you reason about the code and enables laziness. The `rec` semantics are simply not suitable for overriding.